# Uniswap JS SDK and Ethers js trying to swap eth for tokens

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I am trying to swap tokens using a js script that can be used to swap ethereum for any token. The problem is that some of the tokens I try and swap for will provide the error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: InsufficientInputAmountError". However, if I try and swap for a different token it works as it should. I know the token that raises the error is compatible with uniswap since I have bought some through their website and received no error.

```
const {ChainId, Fetcher, WETH, Route, Trade, TokenAmount, TradeType, Percent, Token} = require('@uniswap/sdk');
const {ethers} = require("ethers");

let Web3 = require('web3');
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("INFURA_KEY"));

function toHex(Amount) {
   return `0x${Amount.raw.toString(16)}`;
}

const chainId = ChainId.MAINNET; 
const tokenAddress = '0x094F00Cb5e31Ab6164E3CAcb654e8D6c2b3b471C';

const provider = new ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider('homestead', 'ETHERSCAN_KEYY');

const init = async () => {
   const gas = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
   const token = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, tokenAddress, provider);

   const weth = WETH[token.chainId];
   const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(token, weth, provider);
   const amountIn = '10000000000000000';
   const route = new Route([pair], weth);

   const trade = new Trade(route, new TokenAmount(weth, amountIn), TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);
  
   const slippageTolerance = new Percent('1', '100');
   const amountOutMin = toHex(trade.minimumAmountOut(slippageTolerance));
   const path = [weth.address, token.address];
   const to = 'MY_KEY';
   const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) + 60*20;
   const value = toHex(trade.inputAmount);

   const signer = new ethers.Wallet('MY_PRIVATE_KEY');
   const account = signer.connect(provider);
   const uniswap = new ethers.Contract(
       '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D',
       ['function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)'],
       account
   );

   const tx = await uniswap.swapExactETHForTokens(
       amountOutMin,
       path,
       to,
       deadline,
       {value, gasPrice: gas}
   );     
   console.log(tx);
}

init();
```

Functioning Token Address: 0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f
Non-Functioning Address: 0x094F00Cb5e31Ab6164E3CAcb654e8D6c2b3b471C

The issue seems to be when defining const trade since the script doesn't run beyond that. I have looked through and don't know of any reason that most tokens seem to work but a few don't (even if they work on the uniswap website). I am pretty new to JS and working with ethers/uniswap so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a pool for that token on uniswap. I was also facing the same issue for Eth to usdc swap on the Goerli network. First, add the token into the pool and then make a pool with ether.